# Repeater Item template loading

Tags: asp.net

On a web page I have a repeater that I want to assign a template to it:

```
 repeater1.ItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("Template.ascx");
```

On this template i have a buttons. I need to handle the Click events of those buttons.
Is it possible to handle then on web page's codebehind file or I must create a codebehind file for Template.ascx?

Because if create a codebehind for Template.ascx I can't access properties that were declared on the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data-bound controls use a technique called [event bubbling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719644%28VS.71%29.aspx) that allow a child control to propagate events up the control hierarchy. When a button is clicked the event 'bubbles' up to the containing repeater control. You can then determine which button raised the event by checking the `CommandName` property of `RepeaterCommandEventArgs` and then perform the appropriate actions.

In the user control.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />
```

In your parent page handle the ItemCommand event of the repeater control.

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Update":
            //Add update logic here...
            break;
        case "Delete":
            //Add delete logic here..
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties as soon as you have access for desired control.To do this,you need to search for Button in [RepeaterItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.aspx) your Repeater control.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
   (item.Controls[0].Controls[1] as Button).Click += new EventHandler(ClickHandler);
```

First Controls property is container for item and second one is your content which means in your case is your button control.

Be adviced,if your template control has no action over your desired page,for databinding purposes may be,you should allow it under code side of your template page.

Best of luck

Comment: I do this this on my web page right (not in Template.ascx.cs)?

Comment: Yes,You will do this where you placed your repeater control,
not in Template.ascx